# Code javascript in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ajax

Can I copy this code in my [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) APP.
I'm new in AngularJS and I want to know. If  I can copy this code done in javascript in my AngularJS APP

```
function callWS(url, type, dataType, data) {
    var resultado = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        dataType: dataType,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: data,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            resultado = data;
        },
        error: function(e, msg) {
            console.log(msg + ' en ws ' + url);
        }
    });

    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Use `$http` service in angular..Not `$.ajax`..

Comment: Why....?? What is the diference

Comment: [`The $http service is a core Angular service that facilitates communication with the remote HTTP servers via the browser's XMLHttpRequest object or via JSONP.`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the same code with the help of $http in angular JS:

**See below code:**

```
var myAngApp = angular.module('AngularApp', []);  
myAngApp.controller('customController', function ($scope, $http) {  
    $http({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        dataType: dataType,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: data,
        async: false,
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
        $scope.customers = data.d.results;  
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
        });
});
```

Hope this will help you..!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the code of core JavaScript in AngularJS but some different rules and code style. 
Here ajax code you are going to copy but i suggest you '$http' service of AnuglarJS.
For More information here:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Angular, you don't need to use jquery functions.
Use Restangular to handle Rest API Restful Resources. It's powerfull and easy:
https://github.com/mgonto/restangular